# Twilio Webhook Validation

Tags: validation, twilio, webhooks

As seen here (https://www.twilio.com/docs/autopilot/actions/collect)-Example 6 you can use a webhook to validate user input further:
I have created a function in Twilio for that webhook in order to validate an ID number, however I am not sure what to return to show a positive  and negative response.

```
    exports.handler = function(context, event, callback) {
        responseObject = {"actions":[
            { "say": { "speech": "That is correct" } }
        ]};
           callback(null,responseObject);
    };
```

but what happens in the code is that is that I do not get the response object just a one of the messages under the "on_failure" messages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

[To respond to the validate webhook](https://www.twilio.com/docs/autopilot/actions/collect#collect-validate-webhook) you can return one of two responses.

Autopilot expects the following JSON response when the value **is valid**:

```
{
   "valid" : true
}
```

Autopilot expects the following JSON response when the value **is not valid**:

```
{
   "valid" : false
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much another Twilio representative also got back to me over email with the same response so the new code,that works, holds:  let responseObject = {};   responseObject ={"valid":false }; and  responseObject ={"valid":true  }; depending on the test case. Just a heads up for anyone who also has this issue the true case will not output correctly if the "on_complete" is invalid.